# Handle JSF validation errors in presentation layer avoiding h:message

Tags: validation, jsf

Is there a way to let JSF do validations for my inputs but let me control how to display the validation errors? I want to avoid using `h:message`

I find it making my code too messy when I write a `h:message` component below every input components inside forms needing validation support. Since there are several forms on the page using `h:messages` is not an option as that would show the error messages of other forms as well. So I want to handle the error messages sent after validation to the presentation layer & do the errors presentation task myself using JS/Jquery. So how do I handle errors thrown by JSF validation service?

Comment: Why can't you use `h:messages`? When you submit a form, only *that* form will be validated, and only *those* error messages will show up. I tend to use a `p:growl` for global only messages, and `p:messages` for form specific messages.

Comment: because I have several forms on page & each of them require validation support, in case, i include h:messages inside each form then all the messages related to one form will be displayed in another form, not something I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just conditionally render the `<h:messages>` based on [`UIForm#isSubmitted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html#isSubmitted%28%29).

```
<h:form binding="#{form1}">
    <h:messages rendered="#{form1.submitted}" />
    ...
</h:form>
<h:form binding="#{form2}">
    <h:messages rendered="#{form2.submitted}" />
    ...
</h:form>
<h:form binding="#{form3}">
    <h:messages rendered="#{form3.submitted}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

Or just bring in some ajax magic and update the current form only instead of the entire view.

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...><f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" /></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...><f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" /></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...><f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" /></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

---

> *So I want to handle the error messages sent after validation to the presentation layer & do the errors presentation task myself using JS/Jquery.*

Create a [custom component or renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html) which replaces the `<h:messages>`.